# Why Extension Functions are not working on ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I am very new to Android development in Kotlin. I have an ArrayList consisting two ArrayLists of Double type. I want to discard/ slice everything after the first element inside the Big ArrayList. On coming across the properties described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) on Kotlin's page, I found some functions like `dropLast`, `take` etc. However, they don't perform on implementation also there is no error. I am still getting the same output as input having the same length. Although the functions like `add`, `get` under `Functions` column are working fine. I am surely missing something here. What would be the way for achieving this?

Below is a dummy code:-

```
fun padding(tokenizedinput : ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>) : ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> {
    var temp_storage = tokenizedinput // of size 2
    temp_storage.take(1) // OPTION 1. Only want to have first element in this ArrayList
    temp_storage.dropLast(1) // OPTION 2. Only want to drop 1 element from the end
    println("FInal size: "+ temp_storage.size) //still size 2. Why not 1!?
    return temp_storage
}
```

Comment: I removed the question mark from your title, as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>?` can be a data type (to indicate that it is nullable) and that is a bit confusing to people reading :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.take(n)` or `List.dropLast(n)` would `return` a new list with the operation. It would **NOT MODIFY** the existing list. Try logging or printing this way :-

```
println(temp_storage.take(1).size) // would be 1
println(temp_storage.dropLast(1).size) // would be 1
```

> The above outputs would be `1`, iff the size of the List is `2`

To convert to the existing list use :-

```
temp_storage = ArrayList(temp_storage.dropLast(1)) // need to cast it to ArrayList<T> before assigning
```

Comment: So, can I do `temp_storage = temp_storage.dropLast(1)`? Will this modify the existing list?

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat yes it should

Comment: If I do that, I am seeing the error: `Type inference failed. Required: ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>. Found: List<ArryList<Double>>`, when I did `temp_storage = temp_storage.dropLast(1 )`

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat I have edited the answer please check !

Comment: Ah yes, now I get it. The returned `List` from the function has to be wrapped into `ArrayList`. It worked. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

```
temp_storage.take(1)
```

This returns a revised `List`. It does not modify the `List` on which you call it. You are ignoring the returned value.

```
temp_storage.dropLast(1)
```

Same — you are ignoring the work that the function is doing.

```
println("FInal size: "+ temp_storage.size) //still size 2. Why not 1!?
```

It is the same size because nothing that you did modified it.

> What is the way of achieving this?

If I am understanding what you want, use:

```
fun padding(tokenizedinput : ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>) = arrayListOf(tokenizedinput[0])
```

Here, we:

- Get the first element of tokenizedinput
- Wrap that in an `ArrayList`, since you wanted an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` response

Comment: At the end in your answer, if I understood it correctly, `arrayListOf` is creating another ArrayList which gets the first element value?. If so, can't I modify the existing ArrayList `temp_storage`?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what the other answers have already said, from the actual class which contains this method:

The **take** method:

```
/**
 * Returns a list containing first [n] elements.
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if [n] is negative.
 * 
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Transformations.take
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.take(n: Int): List<T> {
    require(n >= 0) { "Requested element count $n is less than zero." }
    if (n == 0) return emptyList()
    if (this is Collection<T>) {
        if (n >= size) return toList()
        if (n == 1) return listOf(first())
    }
    var count = 0
    val list = ArrayList<T>(n)
    for (item in this) {
        if (count++ == n)
            break
        list.add(item)
    }
    return list.optimizeReadOnlyList()
}
```

and also the **dropLast**:

```
/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements except last [n] elements.
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if [n] is negative.
 * 
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Transformations.drop
 */
public fun <T> List<T>.dropLast(n: Int): List<T> {
    require(n >= 0) { "Requested element count $n is less than zero." }
    return take((size - n).coerceAtLeast(0))
}
```

which can be found in `_Collections.kt`

This means that it returns a list, it doesn't modify the original collection

Comment: I understand, but then how to modify the ArrayList?. Should I create another ArrayList and save everything there or Can I make changes to the existing one?

Comment: I was just missing the wrapping part for the resulted List. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: no problem, sorry for the delayed reply there I didn't see your comment, you can assign the result to another arraylist as you have probably figured out :)